# Mysql query to get value from list of values in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that stores the action id list of items in comma separated form and now I want to get the description list from ids in comma separated form with MySQL query.

I have two tables:

```
table1: action_master                         table2: object_action

id   action                                   items      actions_id_list
-------------                                 ---------------------------
1    talk                                     Human      1,2,4
2    walk                                     Dog        3
3    bark                                     Fish       4,5
4    eat
5    swim
```

Now I want to write a select query that can produce an output as follows:

```
items      actions_desc_list
-----------------------------
Human      talk,walk,eat
Dog        bark
Fish       eat,swim
```

Note: I don't have option to store action description list in object_action table directly. I have to use the ids.

Comment: *"stores the action id list of items in comma separated"* Here is your problem. Don't store serialized keys. Time to think about database normalization.

Comment: Thank you @Cid for the prompt reply. Yes you are completely true that normalization can solve this issue in a easy way. Since I have so many fields that will have comma separated ids in same table like shown above, I have to break it down and make multiple small tables for the normalization and that is the final stop for me as well. But I wanted to know if there are any way to write a query that can make the expected result possible as asked above. Thanks!! :)

Comment: @anishroniyar . . . Expend your effort fixing your data, not trying to work around problems in your data model.

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff , I will take care of that in future. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**General consideration of situation**

You should not store comma separated lists as values in a column. This breaks normal forms in database. You should think about `normalization` process. The reason you have an issue right now is because of that comma separated list got designed this way in the first place. Notice, there is no proper way to create `FOREIGN KEY` constraint as well in here.

**Solution**

That said, since you are more likely than not, not able to perform schema redesign (if possible, at least inform someone who can to avoid future problems) you could use `FIND_IN_SET` MySQL function as a `JOIN` condition, and then `GROUP_CONCAT` your results.

`FIND_IN_SET(f1, f2)` returns the position of `f1` string within `f2` string. If we put it in a condition of `> 0` it will return `TRUE` for when `f1` exists within `f2`.

In your case:

- `f1 == action_master.id`
- `f2 == object_action.actions_id_list`

**Sample data**

```
create table action_master( id int, action varchar(10));
create table object_action (items varchar(10), actions_id_list varchar(15));

insert into action_master values (1,'talk'), (2,'walk'), (3,'bark'), (4,'eat'), (5,'swim');
insert into object_action values ('Human','1,2,4'),('Dog','3'),('Fish','4,5');
```

**Query to produce result**

```
select 
    oa.items
  , group_concat(am.action order by am.id) as actions_desc_list
from object_action oa
inner join action_master am on
  find_in_set(am.id, oa.actions_id_list) > 0
group by oa.items
```

See **[LIVE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d05f6/1/0)**

**Result**

```
items   actions_desc_list
-------------------------
Dog     bark
Fish    eat,swim
Human   talk,walk,eat
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Kamil for the solution. This worked.